# How is $ (z_1 \bar {z_2})(\bar {z_1}z_2)= (z_1 \bar {z_2}) \overline {(z_1 \bar {z_2}}) $?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number equation

> $|z_1z_2|^2 =(z_1z_2)(\bar{z_1} \bar{z_2})= (z_1 \bar {z_2})(\bar {z_1}z_2)= (z_1 \bar {z_2}) \overline{(z_1 \bar {z_2}}) $

I know that you can split the $|z_1z_2|^2$ into $(z_1z_2)(\bar{z_1} \bar{z_2})$ as $z \cdot \bar z = |z|^2$

And I know that you can separate them into $(z_1 \bar {z_2})(\bar {z_1}z_2)$ from $(z_1  {z_2})(\bar {z_1} \bar {z_2})$ due to commutative law.

However, I can't understand it conceptually as to how $ (z_1 \bar {z_2})(\bar {z_1}z_2)= (z_1 \bar {z_2}) \overline {(z_1 \bar {z_2}}) $?

May I know the reasoning? Thanks

Comment: $\overline{\overline{a}}=a$ and $\overline{ab}=\overline{a} \overline{b}$

[\overline{\overline{a}}=a and \overline{ab}=\overline{a} \overline{b}]

Comment: @QED can you type without the dollar sign as I cant view your syntax. Thanks

Comment: @Shreamy: you can right-click on the formula to see the Latex code.

Comment: $\overline {z_1 \overline {z_2 } }  = \overline {z_1 } \overline {\overline {z_2 } }  = \overline {z_1 } z_2 $ since $\bar {\bar {z } }=z$.

Comment: @Gary so because they are equivalent, I can just swap to any one of the equivalents ?

Comment: They are equal. It is like replacing $4$ with $2+2$.

Comment: @Gary Thank so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question follows from these two properties of complex conjugation:

1. It it self-inverse: $\overline{\overline{z}} = z$.
2. It distributes over multiplication: $\overline{z_1z_2} = \overline{z_1}\cdot\overline{z_2}$

The self-inverse property should be obvious: If $z = a + ib$, then $\overline z = a - ib$, and $\overline{\overline{z}} = a - (-ib) = a + ib = z$.

For the distributive property, let $z_1 = a + ib$ and $z_2 = c + id$.  Then:

$$z_1z_2 = (a + ib)(c + id) = (ac - bd) + i(ad + bc)$$
$$\overline{z_1z_2} = (ac - bd) - i(ad + bc)$$
$$\overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2} = (a-ib)(c-id) = ac - iad-ibc + i^2bd = (ac - bd) -i (ad + bc)$$

So, from these two properties, $\overline{z_1 \overline{z_2}} = \overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{\overline{z_2}} = \overline{z_1} \cdot z_2 $.